# Setting the end_time value the same as start_time value in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Rails 6.0.3

I am using a form to schedule meetings.
It is being used for both single time meetings that span over several days (with start_time and end_time) and tasks that last only one day.

For singular day meetings, I need the end_time to be set to the same value as start_time, without user selecting it.

I have tried many things in the controller, but can't work it out.

How would you go about this.

Thanks for the help

```
<div class="border border-grey-light rounded" style ="padding: 10px;">
  <%= form_with(model: meeting, local: true, :html => {:id => "flatpickr-form-single"} ) do |form| %>
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= form.label :name, class: 'label' %>
      <%= form.text_field :name, required: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Task name" %>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-6">
      <%= form.label :body %>
      <%= form.rich_text_area :body, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="start_time_result mb-6" style ="width: 30vw;">
      <%= form.label :start_time, class: 'label' %>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between max-w-md">
        <%= form.text_field :start_time, data: { behavior: "flatpickr" }, placeholder: "Date and time select ...", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" field" style ="width: 30vw;">
      <%= form.label :end_time, class: 'label' %>
      <div class="end_time_result flex items-center justify-between max-w-md" >
        <%= form.text_field :end_time, data: { behavior: "flatpickr" }, placeholder: "Date and time select ...", class: "form-control required" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-primary text-base py-1.5 px-5", value: "Confirm" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  const selectElement = document.querySelector('.start_time_result');

  selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const end_time_result = document.querySelector('.end_time_result');
    end_time_result.textContent = `${event.target.value}`;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know it's a single day meeting without the using selecting the end time?

Comment: Good question. I am using jQuery to put the form on the page, and the user selects either a single day meeting or meeting spanning over several days. The form is saved into 2 partials thats render depending on which button is clicked

Comment: but do u need the end date to be visible in the form? If so I think javascript is the way to go. Put a change event listener on the start date and set the end date there

Comment: Thats great, thank you. I added a change event listener to the start_time. I've got it working so it replaces the ```<div>``` of the end_time with the start_Time, but how do I change the end_time form value. I've added the script to my question

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `before_action` in the controller and set the `end_time` parameter value to the same as the `start_time` from there.